# When you save a document library as a Template, can you save a security group with it?

Tags: document-library, document-template

I would like to have an app (Knowledge Libary) with automatically configured settings (like an alert when a document is uploaded).  If I configure a Document Library and save it as a template, can I save alerts, content types, and security group with it?  I want All Domain Users to have read access to the document library by default.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use sharepoint default alerts when document is uploaded... For your first requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Content Types are included in the template, But I think Alerts and Security is not, when you create the list it will by default inherit permission from the list.

What you could do is to have an library request list that would achieve something like that after item is created (with the target where the library is created) and Workflow would create library, apply security and alerts (not sure if the last one can be achieved with out of the box wf)

Comment: Hi Marek... could you just explain a bit more on what you mean by Library Request List?  Thanks!

Comment: you set up a list with a workflow attached to it. so when user creates an request (by creating item it that list) for knowledge library the workflow starts automatically. It creates this library, assigns permission as needed.